# How do I navigate to next screen after validation?

Tags: flutter, dart, validation

```dart
SizedBox(
  height: 50,
  width: 160,
  child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          color: const Color(0xFF0890F2)),
      child: TextButton(
          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
            backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF223843),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            final form = _formkey.currentState;
            if (form != null && form.validate()) {
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => MyLoginPage()));
            }
          },
          child: const Text(
            'Sign Up',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ))),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign false on null case like

```dart
onPressed: () {
  final isValided =
      _formkey.currentState?.validate() ?? false;
  if (isValided) {
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => MyLoginPage()));
  }
},
```

Find more about [forms/validation](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/validation)

Comment: I tried this but didn't work. I guess something is wrong in my validation

Comment: try to check `_formkey.currentState` by printing if it is null or not. & make sure add key on form widget

Comment: _formkey.currentState is null

Comment: Then I assume you didnt use the key like `Form(key: _formkey`

Answer (score 0):

Not need to create variable for these you can use directly bcz validate() function returns bool value.

Demo Code :

```
onPressed: () {
   if (_formkey.currentState!.validate()) {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => MyLoginPage()));
   }
},
```

Comment: don't use `!`, it is risky without check null 1st.

Comment: This also didn't work.